# Rails Time Format, result isn't the expected one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got some problems with Rails DateTime

I do this:

```
@now = DateTime.now
```

Result is = **2015-10-05T11:40:23+02:00**

In the next step I do this:

```
@now =  @now + params[:time].to_i.hours
```

in this step I add a number of hours to the actual time. ... That works fine.

Result is probably: **2015-10-05T12:40:23+02:00** (if I add one hour)

Now when I store it to database, it stores this: **2015-10-05 10:40:23**

---

What I recognized is if I fetch the data from Database I got the correct value: **2015-10-05T12:40:23+02:00**

My question is why is it a different value in database? and how does a cronjob react on? which value will it take?

Comment: Actually it depend on your Time Zone set in you rails application. your rails server Time zone is different so it is showing different value in database server. and your cron jon is depend on your Rails server time zone

Comment: okay then It will take that one? 2015-10-05T12:40:23+02:00

Comment: yes it will take your rails time zone. if your updating yor cronjob with rails application

Comment: cronjobs are set with whenever

Comment: yes you can set it with whenever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of the different `Time Zones`. Your time zone is +2 hour from the `UTC`. Database always save time in `UTC`. When you fetch the time then `UTC` time converted according to you time zone.

By default cron job run on the UTC time. But we **can change it**.

For example, we have crown runing at:

```
5 2 3 * * TZ="UTC" /do/command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

By default `TZ="UTC"`, but we can change it: `TZ="America/New_York"`

```
5 2 3 * * TZ="America/New_York" /do/command > /dev/null 2>&1
```